# Ryzen 5x GPU always in D0 state

Tags: 22.04, hardware, gpu, amdgpu, amd-ryzen

Ubuntu 22.04,
linux-oem-22.04b (kernel 6.0, same behavior on 5.15)
asus vivobook 15x

```
cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_state
D0
```

the state is D0 even when **only** one terminal is running (should be D1-D2 or D3 in idle)

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/amdgpu_pm_info
```

shows temp `44-45C`

laptop's rear is always hot

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver
amd-pstate
```

Power consumption in idle ~ 5-6w.

What can be done ?

**EDIT:**

```
amdgpu: dpm has been disabled
```

dmesg shows that dynamic power management is disabled for gpu

the cause is still not known

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find the reason, but removing built-in gnome power-profiles and installing tlp did the job better:

```
sudo systemctl mask power-profiles-daemon.service
sudo apt purge --auto-remove power-profiles-daemon
```

tlp:

```
sudo apt install tlp
sudo systemctl enable tlp.service
```

reboot